# Facebook Application Secret for multiple websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-social-plugins

I am having 25 websites and I am using Facebook Register plugin http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ it needs a redirect url where the form is posted and to parse signed url a secret key. I need to use it on multiple websites . I see that in app I have to use Site url . Is there anyway to get it working on all sites with one application ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the websites are on different domain name, then you have to create one Facebook application per website on the [Facebook developer website](http://developers.facebook.com).

This comes from the fact that, for security reasons, Facebook controls from where is coming the request : it has to match with the domain name you set in the settings of the app.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How about setting an iframe running from just one site and use that on all 25 sites . Does it break and terms and conditions of Facebook ?

Answer (score 3):

The multiple domain is a fake workaround, you can not specify multiple domains without proper associated URLs (blocks below in the app configuration).
See answer from a facebook developer here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/270196709754345

Answer (score 0):

Since Facebook requires that the App Domains are derived from the Site URL or Mobile Site URL, if you set the Site URL to mysite_1.com and the Mobile Site URL to mysite_2.com you can then set the App Domain to both mysite_1.com and mysite_2.com; thereby using the same AppId for both sites. I successfully implemented this solution.

You may be able to extend this beyond 2 web sites by adding platforms that require the specification of URL's (e.g. Page Tab) but I did not test it.